# Get the value of an observable in the template angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs-observables

i have trouble to set the boolean value of the observable in my template so as to disable a button.

In my component

```
public hasAccess$: Observable<boolean>; 
this.hasAccess$ = this.store.select(hasAccessGetStudentData).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$));
```

In my template

```
 <button [disabled]="(hasAccess$ | async)"  (click)="add()"  >
      add new student
 </button>
```

[image]

Comment: Declared is a `hasAccess$` variable whereas the assignment is to `hasWriteAccess$` variable. They aren't the same.

Comment: @MichaelD i did a typo in my question, but the issue remains the same

Comment: my guess is you wanted to add `!` to negate the expression: `[disabled]="!(hasAccess$ | async)"`

Comment: @Andrei thank you it works :) have a super amazing weekend same for

Comment: @MichaelID thank you also, enjoy your weekend